# What is the equivalent of code before return of React FC , in React class component?

Tags: reactjs

assuming I have the following react functional component

```
const Component = (props) => {
 // Here the code I want to execute 
 doSomething()
 return <div></div>

}
```

What is the equivalent of this in react class component ?

Answer (score 1):

`doSomething` will be called on every render. So it's the same as calling it in the `render()` function of a class component.